# SVN Host with directory user permissions

Tags: svn

I'm looking for a good SVN host website that gives me the ability to restrict user access to  specific directories WITHIN the repo? I know you can do it with a custom SVN install, but setting up my own SVN server is out of the question at the moment.

Any one with some good recommendations? I've been doing some research and sending emails off but so far no one has said yes they support this.

Thanks for your help.

Phill.

Comment: github.com should be good

Comment: I was looking for an SVN host, as opposed to git. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Github can be used for both Subversion and Git. You can checkout from Github either way. What you can't do is set permissions which is something you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Check [codespaces.com](http://www.codespaces.com). They support granular directory permissions (which can be set through their web gui).